# Identification of a PDE

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I cannot find the following equation
$$u_t=u^2u_{xx}$$
anywhere in the literature. Could someone please point me in the direction of what's been published on this?

Comment: This is a nonlinear parabolic equation, with non strict parabolicity. Not much exists in the literature, many years ago we did some work on this kind of problem, which has some interesting features

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona I was able to find your paper, https://arpi.unipi.it/handle/11568/49107#.WdVdv1ftLIo useful for my application. Thank you.